# Does AWS ElastiCache memcache support SASL authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Does AWS ElastiCache memcache support SASL authentication? So far haven't found any information on this.

Comment: Did you ever find out whether AWS ES supports SASL?

Comment: AFAIK it did not.

Comment: ...so, if you have strict security requirement, I would look into encrypting all data in ElastiCache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support. See this repository below to find out how to implement it.
https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto